# AFrame and ar.js - custom markers not working

Tags: google-maps-markers, aframe

I've been trying to use custom markers... but it does not seem to work. Anyone else have this issue?
I can get the hiro marker to work, as well as the barcode markers.

```
<a-marker-camera preset='custom' type='pattern' url='pattern-test-02.patt'>
<a-box position='0 0.5 -5' material='opacity: 0.5; side: double;color:red;'>
<a-torus-knot radius='0.26' radius-tubular='0.05'
animation="property: rotation; to:360 0 0; dur: 5000; easing: linear; loop: true">
</a-torus-knot>
</a-box>
</a-marker-camera>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please visit the help center, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve your question.